# Change Command Prompt - Variables are literal, and changes to .bashrc or .bash_profile not making a difference

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

Trying to change my command prompt in OS X 10.8 / Mountain Lion. Changes to ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile do not make any difference. Like:

```
export PS1="\W \$"
```

It defaults to the host name ("\h\%"). Even if I try to set PS1 in the terminal, it changes but displays the variables literally, as below:

```
ws10% PS1="\W \$"
\W $
```

(with ws10 being the host name)

My ~/.bashrc file:

```
export PS1="\W \$ "
```

Any ideas? I keep getting lost when I cd up and down the directory structure! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Clearly the `bashrc` in your home directory is getting sourced since you're seeing the changes to your prompt.  At this point, I'd recommend copying the system `bashrc` from `/etc` and starting fresh. Edit the `PS1` variable after copying it over.

Comment: I don't think bashrc is getting sourced... the changes to bashrc don't show up in the terminal at all. The change above was from literally typing PS1 at the command prompt

Comment: Okay.  That's a potentially different problem.  `~/.profile` really is a good place for this. Regardless, you should see the update if you export `PS1` at the commandline.  Strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically on Mac OS X, only `.bash_profile` is executing when starting a new terminal. A common solution is to source one file into the other, for example in `~/.bashrc`:

```
[ -r ~/.bash_profile ] && source ~/.bash_profile
```

Apart from that, your example works perfectly fine for me when put in .bash_profile. If you still experience problems, maybe you are overlooking something else?

Comment: But default value for `PS1` in Mac OS is set in `/etc/bashrc`. It's done conditionally--i.e if `PS1` exists (it's a login shell) then `PS1` is assigned a value.  All that happens in `bashrc`.

Comment: @ephsmith, my point is ~/.bashrc is typically not executed when starting a new shell.

Comment: try moving your `profile` or `bash_profile` to `bashrc` and see what happens.  It is sourced for all shells--not just login shells.

Comment: @ephsmith, I am talking about ~/.bashrc, not /etc/bashrc

Comment: Also, /etc/bashrc is sourced in /etc/profile, that's why it is executed for all shells.

Comment: I've never had this issue before... On my previous machine, I changed ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile and voila. Could it have something to do with homebrew or rvm? Any way to debug the loading of the terminal or to say "which profile"? It's got to reading `PS1="\h%"` somewhere.

Comment: For sure. That explains why.

Comment: @JohnHarper, then likely one was already sourcing the other.

Comment: Not fixed yet... I meant that on my old machine I had no issues with changing bashrc or bash_profile. Still can't crack this one.

Comment: @JohnHarper, which part is not fixed? Can you confirm you are editing ~/.bash_profile now? What terminal are you using?

Comment: Using OS X's built in Terminal (v 2.3). My ~/.bashrc is `export PS1='\W \$ '`, my ~/.bash_profile is `export PS1='\W \$ '`, and my /etc/bashrc looks to be the default. Still getting the equivalent of `PS1='\h\%'`

Comment: Then by all means, ~/.bash_profile should be sourced when launching a new terminal. Try doing an echo in .bash_profile.

Comment: There's a reason that changing the bash settings wasn't working... My terminal uses zsh, unbeknownst to me. Thanks to everybody for responding so quickly and thoroughly. I'm sure the next person that comes along looking for BASH help will find this dialogue really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I copied my .bashrc and .profile from an old mac and was seeing this issue.  It came down to the fact that .bashrc was checking for a specific terminal emulation name "xterm-color".  In Mountain Lion, xterm-color was renamed to xterm-16color and a new xterm-256color emulator was added:

check to see if your .bashrc has this check:

```
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
```

and add the new term names, so it looks like this:

```
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color)    color_prompt=yes;;
    xterm-16color)  color_prompt=yes;;
    xterm-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

My .bashrc reads:

```
PS1="\[\e[0;32m\]\u@monkey:\w\$ \[\e[0m\]"
```

i.e. no 'export' in front of the PS1 setting.  Does it help?  I surely get the prompt I have specified.  In addition this line

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

in .bash_profile should also help is you set the prompt in .bashrc.

Comment: `PS1="\[\e[0;32m\]\u@monkey:\w\$ \[\e[0m\]"` gives me a new command prompt of `\[\e[0;32m\]\u@monkey:\w$ \[\e[0m\]` ... just copied/pasted that from my terminal

Comment: The only difference would be that without the export, your prompt will not be set in child processes (for example when executing `/bin/bash` to start a new shell).

Comment: is your prompt definition after: if [ "$PS1" ]; then </prompt/> fi?

Comment: /etc/bashrc starts with: if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi

PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '

Comment: why is fi in front of the PS1 definition?  also, what about the -z?

Answer (score 0):

In **.bash_profile** add at the end following line:

```
[ -r ~/.profile ] && source ~/.profile
```

That made it work again for me under Mountain Lion.

Comment: Or just move the contents of ~/.profile to ~/.bash_profile. If both ~/.bash_profile and ~/.profile exist, bash only reads ~/.bash_profile when it is invoked as an interactive login shell.